"Vanilla cream" from Fibaek's Raw Cakes
I have a copy of Caroline Fibaek's "Raw Cakes" book. There's a recipe for "vanilla cream" that I wanted to make. Here is what it says:
Ingredients:
100 ml water
2 tbsp agave syrup
2 tsp vanilla powder
2 tbsp lecithin granules

Instructions: blend all ingredients

In the photo the "cream" has the consistency of custard. I was suspicious, because it's unclear what would give it the body, but I thought there may be some magical properties of the ingredients that I'm not aware of. There wasn't. The result is like a very watery smoothie. I suspect there may be some ingredient or additional processing instructions missing.
I know of recipes of vegan pastry cream, which involve cornstarch and cooking, but I'm keen to make a raw version. Does anyone know how to fix the recipe above?

That’s a weird recipe. Every one of the ingredients, other than the water, required cooking to produce. In what way is it “raw”?

This seems to be a variant of pastry cream,and I suspect that the lecithin is acting as a replacement for egg yolks. I wonder, entrely speculatively if a small amount of neutral flavoured oil (as a fat) or starch (as a thickener) might help.

@Sneftel -- I'm not into the raw food narrative, so no idea what makes it raw. Just experimenting with unusual recipes and ingredients

@JourneymanGeek -- I thought I replied, but I reloaded the page and the comment was gone... I think this is a great idea to try with some fat, because lecithin needs something fatty to make an emulsion with. I will give it a try. Regarding starches, is there any particular starch you'd recommend that doesn't require cooking? I actually tried adding cornstarch, but it tastes starchy without thermal processing.

I'm in the wierd place where I did food chem as an elective ~20+ years ago and remember these things, so I'm not sure what's best 'practically'. As for non-starchy tasting starches, I don't know what'd work here and taste good.

@JourneymanGeek for flavour I'd think of arrowroot, but like most (all?) starches it needs heat to gel.  It ought to do some thickening without cooking, but whether it does enough without being intrusive is another matter

@Igor any starch you use at home requires cooking. It's possible to create starch that doesn't, but I've never seen it available as pure starch to the home user. You can buy sachets of "pudding" or "custard" powder which you just mix with cold water or cold milk, and some of these are based on such modified starch.
